# how do i set dynamic base url in vuejs app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I want develop an app with vuejs and php. That can be installed in many directory, like

```
https://example.com/path1/app,
https://example2.com/path1/p/app,
```

I don't want to compile vuejs app for each sub path. I have search a lot, but I can't find any solution on this.

**How do I set vue js public path dynamically in vuejs 2?**
I am using @vue/cli 4.0.5 version.
I have also tried using

```
<base href="mybase path"/> // it works for my angular app
```

Please advice me how could do this dynamically?

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got my answer, just need to put a public path to **.**

```
 //in vue.config.js file

 module.exports = {
     ...
     ...
     publicPath:process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'? '.': '/'         
 }
```

thank you all

Comment: Excuse me, you you mean only '/' or '/dist'

Answer (score 1):

in your **app.js** file, write like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
    base: '/base_url_name'
})
```